# Access another directory in other job declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have the following problem :
- I created a job,  which called "job1", contains four directories. How can I access one of those directories if I created "job2". I am using the declarative pipeline

Example: Let's say the first job1 have the following directories and each directory has some files

- The directory has (FirstFile -SecondLife - ThirdFile)

The question is: When I create another job "job2". How can I access one of the above files?

- Is it available to write this line "dir(/workspace/job1/directory/FirstFile)" in second job ?!

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you consider using artifact copy? Or a shared location on that very build agent you're using? How many build agents are configured. To answer that question more information is required. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I have repos in another job. I just need to access this repo in a new job to pull the latest changes. I just want to use the repo that exists in another job. So I asked whether I can access it by dir() command or not?

Comment: Did you try what you are suggesting with Dir step?! give the output of your try if fail. Because this may work, if in your job 1 you are not doing a clean workspace step wc()

Comment: It doesn't work , an error is access denied in workspace folder

Comment: Thanks for you support . Now it works with me . I just added the full path